# 'no module named pip' when running tox

Tags: python, pip, tox

I have a simple tox file running basic python unit tests that I'm trying to run against multiple python versions.

```
[tox]
envlist = py36, py37

[testenv]
setenv =
    PYTHONPATH = {toxinidir}
```

I used pyenv to manage the environments. My `pyenv global` is set to system. I ran `pyenv install 3.5.4 3.6.4` to install and the `pyenv local ${version}` to load them.

`ERROR:   py36: InvocationError for command /Users/$user/workspace/${proj}/.tox/py36/bin/python -m pip freeze (exited with code 1)`

*py36-11.log*

```
action: py36, msg: envreport
cwd: /Users/$user/workspace/${proj}
cmd: /Users/$user/workspace/${proj}/.tox/py36/bin/python -m pip freeze
/Users/$user/workspace/${proj}/.tox/py36/bin/python: No module named pip
```

*Full Tox Output*

```
GLOB sdist-make: /Users/${user}/workspace/${proj}/setup.py
py36 inst-nodeps: /Users/${user}/workspace/${proj}/.tox/.tmp/package/1/tally_ho-0.1.0.zip
ERROR: invocation failed (exit code 1), logfile: /Users/${user}/workspace/${proj}/.tox/py36/log/py36-11.log
================================================================================================================================== log start ===================================================================================================================================
/Users/${user}/workspace/${proj}/.tox/py36/bin/python: No module named pip

=================================================================================================================================== log end ====================================================================================================================================
py37 inst-nodeps: /Users/${user}/workspace/${proj}/.tox/.tmp/package/1/tally_ho-0.1.0.zip
py37 installed: attrs==20.2.0,importlib-metadata==1.7.0,iniconfig==1.0.1,more-itertools==8.5.0,packaging==20.4,pluggy==0.13.1,py==1.9.0,pyparsing==2.4.7,pytest==6.0.2,six==1.15.0,${proj}==0.1.0,toml==0.10.1,zipp==3.1.0
py37 run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='1245480162'
py37 run-test: commands[0] | pytest
============================================================================================================================= test session starts ==============================================================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.7, pytest-6.0.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
cachedir: .tox/py37/.pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/${user}/workspace/${proj}
collected 22 items

tests/test_cmd.py .......                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                [ 31%]
tests/test_config.py ....                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                [ 50%]
tests/test_proj.py ...........                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       [100%]

============================================================================================================================== 22 passed in 0.19s ==============================================================================================================================
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ summary ____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
ERROR:   py36: InvocationError for command /Users/${user}/workspace/${proj}/.tox/py36/bin/python -m pip freeze (exited with code 1)
```

```
$ pyenv --version                                                      
pyenv 1.2.1

$ tox --version                                                        
3.20.0 imported from /Users/${user}/.virtualenvs/${proj}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tox/__init__.py

$pyenv local                                                          
3.6.4
```

I checked the python location and see that there is a pip binary in each python folder. I also tried adding pip to the `require` section of the tox file, setting pip on the `deps` setting and setting `pip_pre` true to see if it would install the latest version, but I get the same result each time. I don't see any other matches with google-fu or Stack so I'm assuming I've made a user error somewhere...

Comment: show the full output, show what version of tox you're using, show any relevant configuration files (also `PYTHONPATH` is almost always not what you want to do, but it's probably not causing your problem)

Comment: Try `/Users/$user/workspace/${proj}/.tox/py36/bin/python -m pip freeze` without `tox`.

Comment: It actually works when I run pip freeze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pyenv had been doing something strange to my paths. I had to deactivate the virtualenv and then reactivate it. Now pyenv works with all python 3 versions I need. For anyone reading this in the future, when I did my research on this problem, it was often related to some kind of path issue.